# DAX measure to prorate monthly volumes (Calendar days vs Producing days)

Tags: excel, dax

I have data table in Excel that consists of 4 columns: Item, Date, Volume, Days. There are several items in the original table (but I am using only two in the example below) and only one entry per month per item. The volume is the quantity produced by the item and the Days column to the number of days in the given month that such item was produced. The following table is an excerpt of the data:
[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBBWv.png)

I am interested in creating a measure that calculate the corresponding volume if the item produced the whole month (Call it Volume_Total_PD, for Producing Days). For example, if an item produced 500 for 15 days, then I want 1000 for a 30-day month for the Volume_Total_PD. I need this to be aggregated to the Quarter and Yearly level.

I called the data table DATA. So far, I created the following measures:

```
Volume_Total:=SUM(DATA[Volume])

DaysInPeriod:=SUMX(
DISTINCT(DATA[Date]),
    DAY(
    EOMONTH(
        DATA[Date],0
        )
    )
)
```

and the following measure, which calculates the Producing Days volume:

```
Volume_Total_PD:=SUMX(DATA,
DIVIDE([Volume],
    IF(DATA[Days]=0,[DaysInPeriod],DATA[Days])))*[DaysInPeriod]
```

If I build a Pivot table like the following:
[Pivot Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh7my.png)

You can clearly see that the Volume_Total_PD measure works at the month level but is wrong at the Quarter and Annual level. The table has two items so, out of interest, I am showing how the Sum of Days and the DaysInPeriod are working as expected. That is DaysInPeriod shows 90 days in first quarter of 2022.

I can of course add an extra column in my data and calculate it in the row context, but the original dataset is large, so I want to avoid creating unnecessary columns that will add to file sizes

Any advice that you can provide to fix the Volume_Total_PD measure will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@mods: sorry, posting as guest does not provide me option to “comment”, so I am “answering“ ..

@Edwin:
Yes, you are right with your “suspicion“. It’s similar to the “famous“ example calculating the sales volume based on quantity and unit price over various items.

You need to calculate in the row context.

If you don’t want to have a calculated column in the source table, you could create a virtual table with this calculated column inside the measure and sum up there.

My suggestion would be to add the calculated column to the source table first. This helps to debug, when you dive into the solution with the virtual table.

Comment: Thank you for getting back on this. I find it bizzare that I can indeed do it at the data frequency source level, but not at the aggregated level. If no other work around, then I guess that I will have to add the column and live with the extra file size!.
P.S.- I did not realise that there was an option to enable comments and not answers, as this is my first post here. I will check for next time

Comment: I hope, I did not misunderstood you. When I used your data sample table to calculate it seems to work. The measure: “SUMX the volume * DIVIDE (DaysInMonth,Days)” I created a connected date table for the date hierarchy. It aggregates correctly to the quarterly level. I put everything in one measure; using a measure inside another measure sometimes “mess up” the aggregation. Rgd comments: it’s me not having enough “points” to answer by comment in the first place. Once you add a comment, I can too. It’s not a big deal, I just shouldn’t use “answer” not having the solution.